# How can I limit access to RoleEnviroment on Azure for IIS Websites?

Tags: azure

I have a setup where the webrole are hosting multiply websites on IIS, dynamic deployment by configurations in the storage account.

There will be 3party sites running on the IIS, and these should not have access to the deployment settings from RoleEnviroment. Are there any ways for me to limit the access for the IIS site such it wont be able to use RoleEnviroment on Azure?

Alittle Update:

Moving the important settings out of the configuration file could work. But what about the  `<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=c1azuretests;..." />`

Cant it be set at runtime instead, as this is also something that 3party sites should not be able to find.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting and smart approach. While there is no direct way to restrict access to RoleEnvironment, there some workarounds:

- Perform sanity check/scan on 3rd party assemblies and deny execution if they refer/use RoleEnvironment (not my favorite, but still a viable solution)
- Move configuration settings out from Cloud Settings file to Azure Storage Table (I prefer this one). Now the potential attacker will have access to Role names and configuration, but will not have access to settings.

Both approaches have pros and cons, but I tend to like the second one the better. It is questionable which one involves more code to write but in either case the code you write will be reusable. And the benefit is bigger and better with the second approach.

**UPDATE**

When I say move Configuration Settings to Azure Tables rather than config settings, I mean all configuration settings. So your storage connection strings will also be there. And you don't have to hard code them in code, but rather read them from Azure Table. This has also some other slight implications, such as you have to implement monitoring system for these settings in Azure Table Storage, to make sure you update them in the code running when you update them in the Table. Like you do in automatic manner when changing configuration of a running service.

I also don't see why would you `just deploy a new package with changed setting.` since you can `change settings while service is running without redeploying the whole service package`! Check the [API Reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460809.aspx), and [walk through guide here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-configure-a-cloud-service/).

Comment: One problem with the last approaches is that if we do not put the storage connectionstring in settings, then we would have to hardcode it in code and, then every time a new deployment has to be made, it needs a change and recompile. Right now we have this as settings, means we just deploy a new package with changed setting. (thanks for the comments)

Comment: Is it possible to use the first approach to detect cases when third party code uses reflection to access `RoleEnvironment` in runtime?

Comment: Ahh I get what you mean now with the table. When I said we deploy a new, it was not a replacement to the old, but a new deployment as we need more power or new sites.  With your update, this means that the connection string to the Azure Tables will be needed to be in the Role Settings or hardcoded, same problem as before. (Your comments are still helping me think in a different way so that is good).

Comment: @sharptooth, the easiest way is listed [here](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/107335-net-dependency-walker) - walk the dependencies of each 3rd party assembly and just cut it if it refers `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime`. This however will effectively block all Azure related stuff, such as use Storage. A more complex solution may be used to check specific method calls.
@s093294, right about connecting to Azure Table.

Comment: @astaykov: That thing says it is "like Depends tool", but the latter only finds static dependencies, not cases when `LoadLibrary()+GetProcAddress()` are used.

Comment: And everything that is not Azure specific, and I don't have the concrete reference how to inspect assemblies for black listing APIs. But I gave hints what can be done to achieve desired goal.